# How do I generate a metamask mobile deep link programmatically?

Tags: metamask, javascript

I found this site. https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/#

Which returns a url like:

https://metamask.app.link/dapp/tipme.cash

However if I change the domain name programmatically it doesn’t work.

Comment: What is the generated link you get?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So from your question I assume you replace `tipme.cash` with a different app domain. If you do programmatic changes, what is the url that you get? E.g. `https://metamask.app.link/dapp/ethereum.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: Yeah I just tried with briskreader.com and it doesn’t open up the site.

Comment: Hmm `https://metamask.app.link/dapp/briskreader.com` works for me.

Comment: weird. it didn't work for me. i just got the default account page. I was trying to figure out if that tool used some api call to create the link, but just adding `<domain>` at the end should work?